# Maximum of the product of two poisson mass functions

Tags: probability, optimization, poisson-distribution

I have two questions regarding maximising the following function defined for $x, y \geq 0$:

$f(x, y) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i e^{-x}}{i!} \frac{y^i e^{-y}}{i!}$ when $x, y > 0$,

$f(0, 0) = 1$,

$f(0, y) = e^{-y}$, and

$f(x, 0) = e^{-x}$

1) Is the value $f(x, x)$ monotonically decreasing with respect to increasing $x$?

2) For a fixed $x$, is the maximum achieved when $y = x$?

Comment: You should first verify that you can interchange the order of differentiation and the infinite sum. What is the radius of convergence for the sum?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by interchange the order. But the sum converges for all $x, y >= 0$, as it is the dot product between poisson probability mass functions with rate $x$ and $y$.

Comment: also, it is the probability of observing the same number of outcomes given independent poisson processes with rate $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's likely the sum converges on all of $R^2$. To decide if $f(x,x)$ is decreasing, just take its derivative and see if it's negative. To do this, however, you need to reverse the order.

Comment: it is probably likely that it does converge for all reals, but I am only interested for the non negative reals.

Comment: I don't remember enough analysis to know whether I can reverse the order of the summation and derivative.

Comment: Review series from Cal 3. In any event, you probably can and so differentiate term by term and see if you can sum the series. Where is the question from?

Comment: It comes from taking the product of two poisson probability mass functions to calculate the probability of observing the same number of outcomes.

Comment: I mean, is it something you came up with or is it a question from a book?

Comment: not from a book.

Comment: Then your conclusion may not be valid. You need to check all steps. Firstly, what's the radius of convergence for the sum?

Comment: I do not know, but I know the sum converges for the domain I specified, since it is bounded by one and each subsequent term in the series smaller than the previous one, and has the same sign.

Comment: That's not a valid argument! You need to review series.

Comment: I don't understand how that is not a valid argument. Unless I am reading this answer very incorrectly: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/62593/66676

Comment: Oh, you didn't word it very well. You're saying that the sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded above and so converges. This isn't entirely obvious and it requires that $x,y\ge 0$. You're probably better off with the Ratio Test. In any event, you have a few things to justify before you can interchange the derivative with the sum. And then you have to decide if the answer is negative. Do you have some reason for thinking the result is valid?

Comment: No I don't, except that it is kind of related to the classical problem of maximising the area of a rectangle with a fixed parameter. Imagine the following problem: In a 1x1 square place n-1 points on the square such that each subsequent point is never to the left or below the previous point. Then you can draw n rectangles connecting the point (0, 0) to the point (1,1) on the square. How do you maximise the area of these rectangles?

Comment: If $n=2$ then the area of the two rectangles will be a function of the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the first point. You can then use Calc 3 techniques to find its maximum. As $n$ increases, you get a function depending on more variables but the same principal applies. But I don't see how this relates to your problem exactly.

Comment: $ \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i e^{-x}}{i!} = 1$ and similarly for $y$. Thus, in my analogy, the value of $x$ and $y$ determines where to place the vertices of the rectangles, and the product of each respective summand is the 'area'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. How are you constructing rectangles from this infinite sum?

Comment: Let the $x$ position of the top right hand corner of $j$-th rectangle be $\sum_{i = 0}^{j}\frac{s^i e^{-s}}{i!}$, for $s \geq 0$. (Need to change variable name to not abuse notation.) Similarly for the $y$ position. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: It's still unclear to me. You want the $i$-th term of the series to represent the area of the $i$-th rectangle? If so, then this rectangle therefore has horizontal side of length $\frac{x^ie^{-x}}{i!}$ and vertical side of length $\frac{y^ie^{-y}}{i!}$. You now want to find $x$ and $y$ that maximizes the total area?

Comment: yep, precisely. I think that the values for $x$ and $y$ that maximises the total area is $x = y = 0$, but I am also interested in the optimisation properties of this problem as given in my two questions.

Comment: By $x=y=0$ you mean that there's just one rectangle, the whole square? The problem could be difficult to solve but you can try the following. First, find the gradient of $f(x,y)$. You can take the partial derivatives under the summation sign. Then substitute $x=y$ into the two expressions and see if you get zero for some value of $x$. If you do, then that tells you that you at least have a critical point on the line $y=x$.

Comment: I have calculated the gradients but have found them unhelpful. I will post these later.

Comment: It's relatively easy to solve the gradient equations to get $x=y$. Back-substituting however gives an equation with no solution. It seems that this function doesn't have a maximum. I'll check my working again.