# On the proof of "The infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n^{-1}$ diverges".

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The following text is from the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by T. M. Apostol :

> **Theorem 1.13** $ \ $ *The infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/p_n$ diverges.*
>
> Proof. The following short proof of this theorem is due to Clarkson [11]. We assume the series converges and obtain a contradiction. If the series converges there is an integer $k$ such that $$\sum_{m=k+1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_m}<\frac{1}{2}.$$ Let $Q=p_1\cdot\cdot\cdot p_k$, and consider the numbers $1+nQ$ for $n=1,2,...$ None of these is divisible by any of the primes $p_1,...,p_k$. Therefore, all the prime factors of $1+nQ$ occur among the primes $p_{k+1},p_{k+2},...$ Therefore for each $r\geq 1$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^r\frac{1}{1+nQ}\leq\sum_{t=1}^\infty\left(\displaystyle\sum_{m=k+1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_m}\right)^t,$$ since the sum on the right includes among its terms all the terms on the left. But the right-hand side of this inequality is dominated by the convergent geometric series $$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\right)^t.$$ Therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(1+nQ)$ has bounded partial sums and hence converges. But this is a contradiction because the integral test or the limit comparison test shows that this series diverges.

Clear simple explanation about the following questions all from the last paragraph would be much appreciated :

$1-$ The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{r} (1+nQ)^{-1}$ is bounded and it was considered $r$ to be finite. How it implies a decision about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+nQ)^{-1}$ i.e. $r \rightarrow \infty$? I don't understand one to the last sentence of the proof why if an infinite series has bounded partial sum then it converges; harmonic series has bounded partial sum but it doesn't converge.

$2-$ I know a bit of real analysis regarding the last sentence but what are the integrals and compared thing to test? How is the integral test in here? What is the limit comparison test in this example? And how they result to the divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+nQ)^{-1}$?

Comment: Harmonic series HAS NOT bounded partial sums.

Comment: For 1.) read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62389/relationships-between-bounded-and-convergent-series) and the answers. If the terms are positive and the partial sums are bounded, then the series converges. Hence the harmonic sum does *not* have bounded partial sum.

Comment: @Crostul - for any $r$ the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{r} (i)^{-1}$ is bounded

Comment: Well, for any $n$, $n$ is bounded (it is finite), but the sequence $\{ n \}_n$ is not bounded. The same holds for partial sums of the harmonic series (they behave like $\log n$).

Comment: You can also have a look at the following resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eN9tQX3JJ4&index=5&list=PL32446FDD4DA932C9

Comment: @DietrichBurde - in this proof from boundedness of series for case of finite $r$ it concludes boundedness of case when $r\to \infty$! The link you provided and I read unfortunately didn't solve my problem

Comment: @Liebe In which proof ? Apostol's proof is OK, you misunderstood "bounded partial sum"; see the other link above.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - the whole problem is that I don't understand the last 3 lines of the text. It writes too much information considering that reader knows everything behind them.

Comment: @MrYouMath - O, no it starts with Euler representation of zeta fn which I dont know about

Comment: @Liebe If you want to seriously tackle Apostol's nice book I think you will need much more than just "a bit of real analysis", and if you want to reach more or less peacefully the advanced chapters you will also need a good deal of abstract algebra, complex analysis and much more about infinite series and all that.

Comment: @Joanpemo - I've studied Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick which I understand your answer but still don't understand the question I asked in the comment below

Comment: I don't know that book but any *decent* book in advanced calculus is way more than enough to understand the basic principles of infinite series used by Apostol in his proof. Perhaps to understand the way they're presented can be a little tough, but the theoric principles are pretty elementary.

Comment: *all* the partial sums are bounded by the *same* bound.  The harmonic series partial sums are bounded by different bounds.  For every N there is a partial sum of the harmonic that is bigger than n.  For every partial sum of this, there is am N so that all partial sums are less.  So for N *no* partial sum is larger than N.  These are exact opposite statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring, as you say, to the last three lines in the text:

The series diverges (which, of course, is a positive one)  since for example

$$\frac1{1+nQ}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{monotonically descending and}\;\;\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+xQ}=\left.\frac1Q\log(1+xQ)\right|_1^\infty$$

clearly diverges, so does the series.

Another way to see it diverges:

$$\frac1{1+nQ}\ge\frac1{nQ+nQ}=\frac1{2Q}\frac1n$$

and the right hand is just a scalar multiple of the harmonic series and thus divergent, so by the comparison test our series diverges.

Comment: $r$ is not infinity in the text when it has been compared to the convergent series. If a partial sum is bounded doesn't imply when $r \to \infty$ remains bounded to arrive a contradiction.

Comment: @Liebe I think you're confunding things: the *positive* series $\;\sum\frac1{1+nQ}\;$ is, on one side, divergent as proved above and in the book, **but also** it's been bounded, when $\;r\to\infty\;$ ,  by the converging geometric series $\;\sum\frac1{2^t}\;$ , and **this is** the contradiction

Comment: I think I can understand the confusion if I know the answer to this: Does "for each $r\ge 1$" in the text means/includes $r \to \infty$? Because with "for each $r\ge 1$" I don't think it means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+nQ)^{-1}$

Comment: Well, clearly: if for an infinite sequence $\;\{x_n\}\;$ it is true that **for all** $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;x_n\le M\;$ , for some constant $\;M\;$, then *also $\;\lim x_n\le M\;$ **in case the limit exists** . In our case, since we have positive series, the limit **always** exists in the generalized case (finite or infinite), since the sequence of partial sums of a positive series is           *always*  monotonic ascending,  so being bounded means the seq. or partial sums converges to a **finite** sum, and thus the series converges *by definition*

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I got it all now! :-)

Comment: @Liebe Good to know, It was a pleasure.